# Align two divs side by side centered without wrapper

Tags: html, wrapper, css-tables

I'm a little rusty with CSS, but I'm hoping someone can help me out. What I really want is to have 2 identical sized/celled tables sitting side by side centered in my page. Here's why I'd like to keep them as 2 individual tables... When the screen is resized more narrow (like on mobile devices), I want the Right table to then sit perfectly centered below the Left table. If I try to do this with tables only, the 2 tables can't sit side-by-side (even if there is enough space). I've read many Q&A's here that lead me towards doing it using a Div wrapper (parent) with the 2 tables inside 2 'child' divs. Problem is, if everything's in the wrapper div, it treats the 2 tables as one big piece and won't send the 2nd table down to the next row when the screen gets more narrow. Short of designing a separate mobile site, any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the code snippet below in full screen mode and try to resize the browser. If the result is what you want, customize it to suit your needs.

**Edit:** You can also use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to change your display for screens with a specific size range, as the edited code shows.

```css
#center {
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}
.table {
  width:45%;
  min-width:300px;
  height:150px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:auto;
}
.table table {
  width:100%;
}
td {
  border:1px solid #990000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.table {
    width:80%;
    float:none;
    margin:auto;
}
}
```

```html
<div id='center'>
<div class='table'>
  <table>
    <td>
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
<div class='table'>
  <table>
    <td>
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked great. There are a few brief points when the tables go vertical as I'm scaling the browser window more narrow where they are not centered, but eventually they snap center. I think that has to do with the Bandcamp players doing some auto-truncating of their own. I could try setting them to absolute widths to stop that, but I don't think I'd be happy with a 'one size fits' all with them. It looks good on desktop and mobile, so I'm very happy. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Pleasure. don't forget to up vote or validate the response :)

Comment: I would vote it all up, but site says I'm too new to have that permission. Thanks again. Just about to make it public!